# Conversion of String to DateTime in based on system date formats in c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I read date time in the following format from csv file '17-07-12 16:39:44 PM' (dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss tt ) and trying to convert that string to DateTime using DateTime.TryParseExact() API. However I receive input string in not valid date time error message. My system Date formats is different from the format I am trying to convert. How to convert the string to DateTime irrespective of what ever the system date time format is.

```
if (DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact("17-07-12 16:39:44 PM", "dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss tt"
                                                 , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
                                                 , DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate) == false)
 {
    throw new ArgumentException("dateToPare", parsedDate);
 }
```

I saw some similar post in this forum, but none of them gave solution to my problem. Please let me know if you need more description

Thanks,

Comment: You can't convert a *string* to a particular format. You can parse it and then convert the *result* to a particular format, but it's really unclear what you're trying to achieve here. Please give examples.

Comment: Hi Jon, I am trying to plot a chart in D3, and mapping X-axis data as DateTime, its working fine only for specific format but i expect it to work for different TimeFormat and TimeZones.

Comment: That still doesn't really help us understand what you need. Again, please give examples of sample input and expected output. It's not even clear to me whether you're trying to parse or format at the moment...

Comment: Hi,this is the code i am using, see here "fr-FR" its only for France but i need to make many other like "en-Us","en-GB" and so on. IFormatProvider culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR", true);DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse(date, culture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);

Comment: Please edit your question with this information, making sure it's properly formatted - and *give example input and required output*. It's still entirely unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: But *still* no examples of input and output, despite me asking three times. Sorry, but I'm done here. Maybe someone else will be able to help you without any further changes, but I'd *strongly* recommend you edit your question more to make it clear what you're trying to achieve. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Answer (score 0):

Firstly convert string to datetime, then convert datetime to universal time before adding it to db.

```
public static DateTime AsUtc(this DateTime value)
{
    if (value.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified)
    {
        return new DateTime(value.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    }

    return value.ToUniversalTime();
}
```

Comment: You can specify that you want a universal time when you parse, using `DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal`.